# SpringWebflow authenticating user of two types

Tags: java, spring, jsf, spring-webflow

I am making a webapp using,
Spring security 
Spring framework.
spring webflow.
I want to authenticate from same login page two different type of user i.e user1 and user2.
Both have different tables in database for them and different entity classes defined for them 
I am using jsf .xhtml page for my login page.
I have used primefaces gui and with help of tabs provided login page for user1 and user2 .
Here is my webflow definition file.

The problem is I want to take values for the user1 and user2 from same view-state with id "welcome" but I dont know how to accept their credential since only 1 model is allowed as i have specified model="student".

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">  


    <var name="student" class="be.project.studNtwrk.domain.StudentEntity"/>
    <var name="mentor" class="be.project.studNtwrk.domain.MentorEntity"/>

    <view-state id="welcome" view="welcome.xhtml" model="student" >
        <transition on="ssignUp" to="userType"></transition>
        <transition on="msignUp" to="userType"></transition>
        <transition on="studentSignIn" to="finish">
            <evaluate expression="studentAuthenticationProviderService.processUserAuthentication(student)" />
        </transition>
        <transition on="mentorSignIn" to="finish">
            <evaluate expression="mentorAuthenticationProviderService.processUserAuthentication(student)" />
        </transition>           
    </view-state>

    <view-state id="userType" view="ChooseUser.xhtml">
        <transition on="student" to="studentsignup" />
        <transition on="mentor" to="mentorsignup" />
    </view-state>



    <view-state id="studentsignup" view="studentregistration.xhtml" model="student">
        <transition on="backToSignIn" to="welcome"></transition>
        <transition on="backToChoice" to="userType"></transition>
        <transition on="confirmSignUp" to="StudentAuthentication">
            <evaluate expression="studentService.createUser(student)"></evaluate>
        </transition>
    </view-state>

    <action-state id="StudentAuthentication">
        <evaluate expression="studentAuthenticationProviderService.processUserAuthentication(student)" />
        <transition on="yes" to="finish"></transition>
        <transition on="no" to="welcome"></transition>
    </action-state>

    <view-state id="mentorsignup" view="mentorregistration.xhtml" model="mentor">
        <transition on="backToSignIn" to="welcome"></transition>
        <transition on="backToChoice" to="userType"></transition>
        <transition on="confirmSignUp" to="MentorAuthentication">
            <evaluate expression="mentorService.createUser(mentor)"></evaluate>
        </transition>
    </view-state>

    <action-state id="MentorAuthentication">
        <evaluate expression="mentorAuthenticationProviderService.processUserAuthentication(mentor)" />
        <transition on="yes" to="finish"></transition>
        <transition on="no" to="welcome"></transition>
    </action-state>

    <end-state id="finish" view="externalRedirect:account" />

</flow>
```

Comment: how is this PF related? Does it work with using a plain h:dataGrid? instead of PF tabs?

Comment: @kukeltje I am using PrimeFaces for jsf components. plz can you explain ur question

Comment: You tagged this question with 'primefaces' but I think that if you use an h:panelgrid instead of a p:tabview, you have the same problem and hence it is not PF related imo and should the primefaces tag be removed

Comment: can u guide me how to remove the pf tag I m newbie

Comment: I think you can remove it by editing the question

Comment: But first try if it fails with an `h:panelgrid` to

Comment: @Kukeltje please can you ...elaborate I don t get it....sorry for the asking :(

Comment: In your application for the login you have two primefaces tabs in a tabview. Remove those and replace those by some baisc jsf elements (panelgrid) or even just a plain html table. Try if you still have the same problem then

Comment: Yes  i am still having the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is separate the "student" and "mentor" each into their own flow (files) and if there is any duplicate logic use flow inheritance and put the duplicate logic in an abstract flow that both the new "student" and "mentor" flows extend.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/reference/html/flow-inheritance.html